# navbar-toggler-right is not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

When I use `navbar-toggler-right` in the `ul` inside the `navbar`, all the stuff goes a little bit outside of the `navbar`, and I don't know how to resolve this.

[image: The image of my navbar]

Here's my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" id="nav-main">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
         <img src="images/logo-menu-2.png" alt="Motiva Mente">
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto navbar-toggler-right">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">CATEGORIAS</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">MUSCULAÇÃO</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">AERÓBICO<a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">FUNCIONAL</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">FISIOLOGIA</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">BIOMECÂNICA</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">NOTÍCIAS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">SOBRE</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTATO</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                    <button id="botao-search" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative that will yield your desired result, is to remove the `navbar-toggle-right` and replace it with  the `ml-auto` class. Additionally, you would want to have your form element separated from your unordered-list element.

You can see how it functions in this [codeply project](https://www.codeply.com/go/TYSul16XVh) I created with your code.

The mark up would look like this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" id="nav-main">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x80" alt="Motiva Mente">
    </a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">CATEGORIAS</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">MUSCULAÇÃO</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">AERÓBICO</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">FUNCIONAL</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">FISIOLOGIA</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">BIOMECÂNICA</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">NOTÍCIAS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">SOBRE</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTATO</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
             <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                <button id="botao-search" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```